# Android Opening file instead gallery

Tags: php, android

How to modified code below so it will display the file directory on the storage instead gallery

and what permission i need to allow

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, most intents do not require any permissions. This is also the case for your Intent.

Some Intents do require a permission like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(...)); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Needs:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

But:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(...)); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Does not, because this intent does not directly call someone, it only shows the dialer with the requested number, and the user has to press `call` first.

In general, you can say that any intent that directly costs the user money, or directly modifies the system, needs a permission.

Comment: I need to open my file browser,  I have change the code into

ntent.setType("file/*");

Comment: Keep in mind that not all phones have installed a file browser.

Comment: After I install a file browser into the phones, it work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement reading and selecting the file in the app itself (i.e. get and display the files directly) as passing it off to a Chooser will depend on the apps installed on the device and which apps the user has selected to choose with. Unless there's a specific reason to limit the user's options, the best practice would probably be to go through their chooser.

If you implement it yourself inside the app, you'll need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.